# NASM Access Pointer value for 5 offsets using mov

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm, offset

mov edx,[00E40608]
I have 5 offsets
00E40608->130->238->360->1C0->484
to get my desired value from this address.
How can I use mov edc,[00E40608] but add these 5 offsets to it?
Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: Where are these offsets coming from? Are they constants? Are they in registers?

Comment: Yes they are constants

Comment: So then add them together in advance to get 0xD0C, and then add that to 0x00E40608. Or have your assembler do it: `mov edx, [0x00E40608 + 0x130 + 0x238 + 0x1C0 + 0x484]`.